# popup-shown listener for a combo box in js using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using select and ng-options to show a combo box in my application.

I want to lazy load the contents of the aforementioned select using a rest call. 
So, i have used ng-click to call a method when ng-click is triggered.

Problem is even if the click is on the combo-box or there's any selection in the combo box, the rest call is triggered.

How can i just bind the event when the combo-box dropdown is shown.

Below is the code snippet of what i've done.

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.ID for item in beanPropertyComboItems" ng-change="onDropdownChange(selected)" ng-click="onDropdownClick(selected)"><option value=""></option></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

More code will help! It sounds like you only want to make the REST call when the select box is first created. You can do this inside a controller or directive you have wrapped around the select. Angular has a directive called [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) for this case as well, but it is highly recommended that you don't use it. Best practice is to initialize scope variables within controllers.

If you want to populate the select box when it is first *clicked*, you can add a boolean flag inside your "onDropdownClick" function to check if it has been populated yet.

Comment: Actually i want to make rest call every time the select box is clicked. i.e. always when the popup is shown and avoid the click event when any selection is made in the combo box item.